# Completely delete EF database in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been messing around with changing my object properties, and that requires me to keep updating my table, but I keep getting errors, so does anyone know how I can just delete the whole DB and start over?

I have this code

```
using (var ctx = new Context())
            {
                foreach (Item2 block in new_Items)
                {
                    ctx.items_db2.Add(block);
                }
                ctx.SaveChanges();

                test = (from b in ctx.items_db2
                        orderby b.Index
                        select b).ToList();
            }
```

I've tried truncating the table but I can't do that since I've changed the object properties, and even when I run the commands from the package manager console to update the table, I get other errors so I'd just like to start from a clean slate.

Comment: Connect with SSMS and go "poof"? (Alternatively, enable that one stupid delete-and-rebuild mode.)

Comment: I don't know how to do either of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from from your code just by running:

```
using (var ctx = new Context())
{
   ctx.Database.Delete();
}
```

Alternatively connect to your database using VS - View --> SqlServer Object Explorer connect to your database server, right click on the database you want to delete and select Delete. You want to check the checkbox to close existing connection otherwise deletion may fail.

Answer (score 1):

If the migrations are not important, I:

1. Delete migrations.
2. Delete all the tables in the database.
3. Run the Enable-migration command.
4. Run the Add-migration command, to add an initial migration.
5. Run the Upgrade-database command. This will rebuild all the tables in the db, and you back to square one :)

I use code first.

Comment: But I can't delete the table since I changed the properties and I don't know how to change it back. Can you just tell me how to delete the whole db, to go back to a state where I didn't have EF?

Comment: What database are you using? What properties have you changed that makes it impossible to delete the tables?

Comment: I don't know, I tried changing it multiple times, now I don't even know how many tables I have. This is for a personal project and all I wanted was to store the value of one property for a bunch of objects because saving them to a file with protobuff was creating huge 200mb file. So that's why I just want to start over

Comment: If you write your connection string I can figure out what database your using. But since you don't know it is probably Sql Server Express. If that is the case you can open the database using Sql Server Management Studio. Here you can see how many tables you have and you can delete them all.

Comment: When I installed EF, I believe my database went to the SQL Server Object Explorer, but I don't know where that it (I can just view it on a side window). I think it's the default if I don't have any SQL software pre installed, which is SQLEXPRESS, so you're right. But where do I open it from?